# WinRT Error: not implemented

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I was trying to use **Windows.Networking.Connectivity.ConnectionProfile** class method **getAttributedNetworkUsageAsync()** method for getting no of bytes transferd by mobile application. But when i call getAttributedNetworkUsageAsync() on **windows phone OS 10**, it throws an error  **WinRT Error: not implemented** . I am new to windows phone development. so, please help me.
Here is my code

```
    var networkInfo = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation;
    var connectivityNS = Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
    var currTime = new Date();
    var result;
    //Set start Time to 1 hour (3600000ms) before current time
    var startTime = new Date(currTime);
    startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours() - 1);

    //Get the ConnectionProfile that is currently used to connect to the Internet
    var connectionProfile = networkInfo.getInternetConnectionProfile();
    var networkUsageStates = {          
        roaming: connectivityNS.TriStates.doNotCare,
        shared: connectivityNS.TriStates.doNotCare
    };

    if (connectionProfile === null) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Not connected to Internet\n\r", "sample", "status");
    }
    else {
        connectionProfile.getAttributedNetworkUsageAsync(startTime, currTime, networkUsageStates)
            .then(successCallback,errorCallback);}
```

Here is the **successCallback** function

```
function successCallback(networkUsage){    
        for (var i = 0; i < networkUsages.size; i++) {                                                      
        result =
        {
            bytesSent: networkUsages[i].bytesSent,
            PacketSent: 0, //not supported in windows
            BytesReceived: networkUsages[i].bytesReceived,
            PacketReceived: 0   //not supported in windows
        };
    }
}
```

here is **errorCallback**

```
function errorCallback(error) {
    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("An error has occurred: " + error, "sample", "error");
}
```

Comment: I think the error means that the specific function wasn't implemented by the development team yet.

Comment: But on windows phone 8.1 documentation it is listed. So does it mean it's not supported on windows phone 10?

Comment: Maybe. I'm sure it will be supported with the final API, but for the moment there is nothing you can do with Win10.

Comment: Thank You friend for your precious time. Thanks a lot